# IOS event mechanism

Tags: iphone, ios, events

I want to communicate between my different modules using events.
Is there an event mechanism in IOS? I'm looking for something similar to BroadcastReceiver in Android.

Thanks.
PB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### between different modules in the same process:

here NSNotification is cool:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter/

---

#### between processes

IOS does not offer any real dedicated means to do this. BUT you can (many do) use custom url schemes for that:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: NSNotification was exactly what I needed. Thanks!